# React component is not loading props after history.goback()

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a component which is updating states on page load with useeffect. But when i use history.goback() function to go back from a component to my bank component useeffect is not working. Here my code ;

bottomnavigator.js :

```
const goBack = () => {
    if (props.history.location.pathname !== "/app/phone" && props.history.location.pathname !== "/") {
      props.history.goBack();
    }
  };
```

bank.js :

```
  const [transactions, settransactions] = useState([]);
  const [bankBalance, setbankBalance] = useState(0);

  const getBankData = async () => {
    if (props.location.state) {
    const res = await Nui.post(props.location.state, {});
      if (res) {
        setbankBalance(res);
      }
    }
  }

  const getTransactionData = async () => {
    if (props.location.state) {
      const res = await Nui.post('GET_BANK_TRANSACTIONS', {});
      if (res) {
        settransactions(res);
      }
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
      getBankData();
      getTransactionData();
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you have listed "no dependencies" (`[]`) in your `useEffect`, so it will run once at the beginning and then never again.  You should either **omit the dependencies** like so:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
      getBankData();
      getTransactionData();
  });
```

Or list the correct set of dependencies like so: (I'm guessing here based on your code, but hopefully I got it right)

```js
  useEffect(() => {
      getBankData();
      getTransactionData();
  }, [props.location.state]);
```

Comment: Actually i tried them both but not working. I tried again after your post but still not working.

Comment: I think this is correct, and explains what happens to OP. But I'll like to add that, it might be a better idea to pass the `getBankData` and `getTransactionData` function into the dep array of the useEffect, and wrapp those in `useCallback` hook where that callback depende on `props.location.state`

Comment: Then I would guess that there's an issue with your routing, that it's not properly depending on the path. We'd need to see more of your code.

Comment: Thanks for help i fixed it. My problem was the condition in functions. props.location.state is null after goback. Thank you again.